# How to find Text - boxes on a web page which do not have any HTML property in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There is no HTML properties associated with TEXT-BOXes in the application , now how to use index to find text-boxes in application and enter values in each text-box.

Regards
Shashank Goyal

Comment: You mean that you do not have <input> tags in the html?

Comment: Showing us some example HTML would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using xpath or css selector if No id attribute present in the HTML .

Do you mean no **< input >** tag for text boxes??

Provide HTML snippet of AUT